# large image pull using docker desktop in windows10 always failed at the end with error "unauthorized: failed authentication"

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop, google-cloud-registry

I am able to pull small-size images using docker desktop but getting issues with a large image of size around 7 GB, We are always getting stuck at the end while pulling large images using docker desktop in windows10 and it's getting failed with the error "unauthorized: failed authentication"

I tried to restart the docker service and also tried to add the below parameter
"max-concurrent-downloads": 1

and also tried to enable the feature "Use containerd for pulling and storing images" and also tried to re-install but there is no success,

Docker desktop version:  20.10.21

Is this the bug in this version, any workaround,

Answer (score 0):

If image download seems stuck during large image pull, then use ctrl+c 1-2 times,
if it's exited after ctrl+c then try again to download, it should start downloading from same layer and then use same ctrl+c when stuck,

It works for me, It seems workaround for this problem,